# LADW Book Determinants: author claims that linearity can be deduced from scalability and invariance under "column replacement"

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

When developing theory of determinants in his well known LADW book (https://sites.google.com/a/brown.edu/sergei-treil-homepage/linear-algebra-done-wrong) Treil, prior to even introducing normed spaces appeals to reader's prior experience to specify the basic desired property of the volume function and then shows that from some basic assumptions one can essentially arrive at the conventional definition of determinants.

So, the author considers parallelepiped defined by a set of vectors (page 75):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLzRDCtln64G5pOEjEb9cTkUBTKJNAvb/view
[image]

He then specifies three properties that the reader should find obvious and intuitive (below my text I also copy a page from his book):

1. Linear scalability of the volume function - i.e. if one of the vectors is doubles the volume is doubled:
2. Additive linearity. This is a bit less intuitive though by closely appealing to 1D, 2 D, and 3D it is possible to accept it.
3. Preservation under "column replacement". By "column replacement" he means that volume is not affected if two one of the vectors a multiple of some other vector is added. Idea here is that volume is area (volume in dimension one unit lower) times height and the height is the distance to that lower dimensional subspace from the "height vector" and such height should not be affected by adding a vector from such subspace.

**He then claims that 2 is really not needed as can be derived from 1 and 3 and I fail to see how 2 can be derived from 1 and 3. Any help would be welcome!**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLzRDCtln64G5pOEjEb9cTkUBTKJNAvb/view

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but in general u_k and v_k (in 2.3) could be linearly independent from all other v....

Comment: to OP's comment-- this concern is isolated to rank deficient matrices. Main techniques use Basis ideas and rank-nullity from chapter 2.  If $\mathbf u_k$ and $\mathbf v_k$ are both linearly independent from all other $\mathbf v_i$ then treated as a matrix the rank is $\leq n-1$ and it has a non-trivial kernel.  Then use (3) column replacement property to kill a column and (1) scaling to show the determinant is zero.  This implies $0=0+0$ for property (2).

Answer (score 1):

I think now, based on comments by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/735806/user8675309 and https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252194/morgan-rodgers I have an answer:

1. In R^n there can be at most n linearly independent vectors so in 2.2 above at least one of the vectors must linearly depend on others.
2. In 2.2 if there is linear dependency amongst n-1 vectors that are in positions other than k then by 2.3 and 2.1 all three determinants in 2.2 are zero and the equality holds.
3. If those other n-1 vectors are linearly independent than at least one of the uk and vk can be expressed as a linear combination of all other n vectors (including the other vector from the pair) , which without the loss of generality can be taken to be uk.
4. Uk can then be expressed as linear combination of {v1,,,,vk,,,,,vn} and then application of 2.3, then 2.1, then splitting into two parts and reverse application of 2.3 to one of the parts will yield 2.2.